# Initializing an array of variables within a class instance in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm coming from a C background, and am running into a problem in Java. Currently, I need to initialize an array of variables within an array of objects.

I know in C it would be similar to `malloc-ing` an array of `int` within an array of `structs` like:

```
typedef struct {
  char name;
  int* times;
} Route_t

int main() {
  Route_t *route = malloc(sizeof(Route_t) * 10);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    route[i].times = malloc(sizeof(int) * number_of_times);
  }
...
```

So far, in Java I have

```
public class scheduleGenerator {

class Route {
        char routeName;
    int[] departureTimes;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      /* code to find number of route = numRoutes goes here */
      Route[] route = new Route[numRoutes];

      /* code to find number of times = count goes here */
      for (int i = 0; i < numRoutes; i++) {
        route[i].departureTimes = new int[count];
...
```

But its spitting out a `NullPointerException`.  What am I doing wrong, and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you need route[i] = new Route() before route[i].departureTimes = new int[count];

Comment: [Lear here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm)

Comment: why dont u use a constructor if u need to initialize it only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you initialize your array

```
Route[] route = new Route[numRoutes];
```

there are `numRoutes` slots all filled with their default value. For reference data types the default value is `null`, so when you try to access the `Route` objects in your second `for` loop they are all `null`, you first need to initialize them somehow like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      /* code to find number of route = numRoutes goes here */
      Route[] route = new Route[numRoutes];

      // Initialization:
      for (int i = 0; i < numRoutes; i++) {
           route[i] = new Route();
      }

      /* code to find number of times = count goes here */
      for (int i = 0; i < numRoutes; i++) {
        // without previous initialization, route[i] is null here 
        route[i].departureTimes = new int[count];
```

Comment: yes, I would too in _real_ code. Put it down like this to emphasize it's important to initialize objects in an array before working with them.

Answer (score 1):

```
Route[] route = new Route[numRoutes];
```

In java when you create an array of Objects, all the slots are declared with there default values as below
    Objects = null
primitives 
    int = 0
    boolean = false

these numRoutes slots all filled with their default value i.e. null. When you try to access the Route objects in your loop the array reference is pointing to null, you first need to initialize them somehow like this:

```
  // Initialization:
  for (int i = 0; i < numRoutes; i++) {
       route[i] = new Route();
       route[i].departureTimes = new int[count];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numRoutes; i++) {
  route[i] = new Route();
  route[i].departureTimes = new int[count];
```